# Python - Internationalization for Telegram bots

Tags: python, internationalization, telegram

I'm using Python **gettext** to translate my Telegram bot messages to pt_BR or leave them in en_US. This is my code:

```
# Config the translations
lang_pt = gettext.translation("pt_BR", localedir="locale", languages=["pt_BR"])
def _(msg): return msg

# Connecting to Redis db
db = redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0)


def user_language(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(bot, update, *args, **kwargs):
        lang = db.get(str(update.message.chat_id))

        if lang == b"pt_BR":
            # If language is pt_BR, translates
            _ = lang_pt.gettext
        else:
            # If not, leaves as en_US
            def _(msg): return msg

            result = func(bot, update, *args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapped

@user_language
def unknown(bot, update):
    """
        Placeholder command when the user sends an unknown command.
    """
    msg = _("Sorry, I don't know what you're asking for.")
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                     text=msg)
```

But, even when the language is pt_BR, the text remains as en_US. It seems that the first declaration of function `_()` (line 3), translates all messages at once, and even when the `_()` function changes in the decorator, the messages doesn't get translated another time.

How can I force the messages to be translated again in the decorator?

Comment: This seems to be thread-unsafe, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I just forgot to declare the **_()** as being global. Here is the right code:

```
def user_language(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(bot, update, *args, **kwargs):
        lang = db.get(str(update.message.chat_id))

        global _

        if lang == b"pt_BR":
            # If language is pt_BR, translates
            _ = lang_pt.gettext
        else:
            # If not, leaves as en_US
            def _(msg): return msg

        result = func(bot, update, *args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapped
```

Comment: Thanks for Jannes Hoke from the telegram.Bot() group (@pythontelegrambotgroup) in Telegram!